# Is claiming to be President after your term ends treason?

Tags: united-states, president

Let's imagine a hypothetical case where a President of the US, having lost an election and after his term expires, continues to go around saying that he is the rightful President and that the guy currently in the Whitehouse is illegitimate.

It seems to me that comes very close to being treason, setting yourself up as an alternative government. How far would such a person have to take their claims before they could be arrested?

If it's not treason, is it some other crime?

Comment: Treason is constitutionally defined, and hence a political act.

Comment: @JamesK the fact that treason is defined in the constitution does not prevent it from being a crime nor a legal matter, and indeed it is also found in the criminal code.  Furthermore, the constitutional definition of treason goes far beyond acts normally considered "political," since one such act is "levying war against the United States."

Answer (score 22):

"Treason" is narrowly defined in the USA.  This is on purpose, the framers of the constitution were familiar with Kings in Britain calling anything they didn't like "treason" and using it as way to repress dissent.

In the USA treason is defined in article III

> Treason against the United States, shall consist only in levying War against them, or in adhering to their Enemies, giving them Aid and Comfort.

So "claiming falsely to be President" is not "treason", and is probably protected free speech, until you bear arms *against* the States.

Note, it is common for former Presidents to retain the courtesy title "President", although there are no powers or responsibilities attached to that title, and they are not *the* President.

Answer (score 11):

The First Amendment (as it's usually interpreted) gives people broad latitude to say whatever they like. It isn't illegal for someone to *claim* to be president when they aren't, it's merely delusional. Psychiatric or psychological intervention would be more appropriate.

If that particular delusion extends itself to certain kinds of actions that constitute a threat to the established order and institutions of the US, *that* would be illegal, though it might not rise to the level of treason. Someone who tried to depose the current president and install themselves in the White House could be prosecuted for any number of crimes, depending on the severity of the act. For instance, if they boldly tried to walk into the Oval Office to claim their 'rightful' seat they might face a mere trespassing charge, while if they plotted to attack the president it could result in conspiracy, assault, attempted murder, or similar charges.

Treason charges would generally be reserved for the most extreme, organized, and dangerous cases: actions which either rise to the level of insurrection or which undercut the sovereignty of the nation. In other words, someone who:

- Attempted to raise a domestic army and stage a revolt
- Petitioned a foreign nation for military support to install themselves as leader
- Threatened to reveal state secrets or otherwise damage the national interest in order to pressure the government into placing them as president

could potentially face a treason charge. But that treason charge would be based on the extreme nature of their actions, not on the delusion that prompted those actions.

Comment: A threat to reveal state secrets would not be treason.  Revealing such secrets would be treason only if the revelation were beneficial to someone who was at war with the US.

Comment: @phoog: It would certainly constitute espionage — which can carry the death penalty, mind you — and I'm not certain where the legal boundary between espionage and treason would be in this case. I suppose we'll have to wait until there's practical case law (which could be any day now...)

Comment: Indeed.  There are lots of serious crimes other than treason.  There is also sedition, which includes trying to thwart the operation of federal law, including election law.  And there is nothing that says there must be a boundary between espionage and treason.  Some acts could constitute espionage, treason, and sedition all at once, or any two of them.

Answer (score 6):

You can *say* almost anything you damn well feel like.  You can claim you're still President and the other guy cheated.  You can claim that you're ordained by God to be President.  You can file pointless lawsuit after pointless lawsuit alleging all kinds of shenanigans until your attorneys start getting hit with Rule 11 sanctions.  You can hold rallies with slogans like "Stop the Steal" and soak the rubes for their hard-earned cash and that sweet, sweet dopamine hit.

That's not treason or sedition.  That's just being a jackass.

If you instruct your followers to take up arms against the United States, then *that's* sedition.  If you solicit help from a foreign power to overthrow the US Government, then *that's* treason.  Our hypothetical loser hasn't done those things.

*Yet*.

Comment: What happens if you instruct people to overthrow the government _without_ arms? You just preach that they should destroy the government, somehow, and perhaps to break laws in the process, but not outright talking about arms. Also, if one did such a thing as a "nobody", would the penalty be mild?

Answer (score 3):

Article 3 Section 3 of the US Constitution defines treason. One would have to [stretch](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution-conan/article-3/section-3/clause-1) the "Levying War" and "Aid and Comfort" clauses to call this treason.